# How to restore Ubuntu to a previous date?

Tags: restore

Is there something like Windows System Restore on Ubuntu? I'm talking about putting the system back to a past time, when the system worked fine. If there is something like that, where is it, and how can I use it?

Comment: LVM snapshots may be what you are looking for.